# How do I center my products column?

Tags: css

I would like to center my products display, but I really don't know how...I have tried several CSS changes but none of them had success...

The products are aligned to the left :\

Here's the link to my website:

Home Page:

http://wwww.buysmartcardsonline.com

Product Page:

http://buysmartcardsonline.com/index.php/contact-cards/siemens-sle5542.html

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about HTML/CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is nothing Magento-related and should better be asked on another StackExchange site, here you go:

```
.col3-layout .col-wrapper {
    width: 1045px;
}

.col3-layout .col-main {
    850px;
}

.product-view {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 468px;
}
```

The main problem is that the wrapper / main columns are too narrow.

Comment: That worked for the product itself: http://buysmartcardsonline.com/index.php/contact-cards/siemens-sle5528.html but for the categorie view it didn't work: http://buysmartcardsonline.com/ . Do you know how can I center the products categorie view? Thanks :)

Comment: Obviously you managed to get it work. If my answer was helpful, please consider to accept it (tick in the left column of the answer).